# how can I make cy.each() operate with my array in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I have fixture file named *alerts-escalation-param.params.json* where I store operations with their fixture path file ,then I have a function command `getOperationData` that get the operation data to use it in the test cases just by calling the operation name .
so the problem that I have is that when I start the tests , in the case when I start using this function *`getOperationData`* I get this error:
`cy.each() can only operate on an array like subject. Your subject was: Object{4}`[`Learn more`](https://on.cypress.io/each)

here is the function `getOperationdata`:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getOperationData', (mode, operationsArrayName = 'operations') => {
        cy.fixture('alerts-escalation-param.params.json').then((params) => {
          const fixturePath = params[operationsArrayName];
          cy.fixture(fixturePath).then((data) => {
            const opData = data.filter((element) => element.mode === mode);
            Cypress.env('fixtureData', opData);
          });
        });
      });
```

and here is the case test where I use it :

```
it.only('should do a search by criteria', () => {
    cy.getOperationData('search').each((searchCase) => {
      cy.setDataAndSearch(searchCase.criteria)
      if (searchCase.expectedRowsCountResult === 0) {
        cy.should(
          'equal',
          cy.getdefaultOperationExpectedValue()
            .numberOfColumnsOnEmptyRow
        )
      } else {
        cy.should(
          'equal',
          searchCase.expectedRowsCountResult
        )
        cy.searchAndGoToDetails(searchCase.criteria)
        for (const dataKey in searchCase.afterOpCriteria) {
          cy.should(
            'equal',
            searchCase.afterOpCriteria[dataKey]
          )
        }
        cy.back()
      }
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to make it work by returning or wrapping the internal results of the custom command

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getOperationData', (mode, operationsArrayName = 'operations') => {
  cy.fixture('alerts-escalation-param.params.json').then((params) => {
    const fixturePath = params[operationsArrayName];
    cy.fixture(fixturePath).then((data) => {
      const opData = data.filter((element) => element.mode === mode);

      cy.wrap(opData);   // this makes the data subset the "subject"
    });
  });
});

cy.getOperationData('search')   // subject is unwrapped and passed to next command
  .each((searchCase) => {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your `cy.getOperationData()` does not yield anything to the `.each()`. Instead, after running `cy.getOperationData()` to set the `Cypress.env()` variable, you can use the data set from that to run the `.each()`.

```js
cy.getOperationData()
  .then(() => {
    cy.wrap(Cypress.env('fixtureData')).each((searchCase) => {
      // code here
    });

  });
```